# I need to attach a monitor to this computer, which cable do I need?

Tags: display

This is an old computer and I require to attach it a monitor (and a keyboard + mouse, I hope usb mouse will still work).

I don't have this cable neither I know the name, I'm too young to remember it, can anyone point me out what's the name of the cable?

Also, is possible to connect a classic vga monitor to this computer, with a converter or something similar?

[image: Monitor]

Comment: Whenever I've seen a connector like that, it has required an adapter cable which splits out to 2 DVI connectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The port is called DMS-59. It was used to make more compact video cards, etc.

From [DMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) on wikipedia,

> "DMS" stands for Dual Monitor Solution. "59" refers to the 59 pins.
>   DMS-59 is generally used for computer video cards. It provides two DVI or VGA outputs in a single connector. An adapter cable is needed for conversion from DMS-59 (digital) to DVI (digital) or VGA (analog), and different types of adapter cables exist. The connector is four pins high and 15 pins wide, with a single pin missing from the bottom row, in a D-shaped shell, with thumbscrews.

Edit:

You can view or buy a compatible adapter on [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003EHCPWM)

With some electrical ability (wiring, soldering), you could use the [pinout](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/DMS59_pinout.svg) to make your own adapter. You would need to buy a DSUB-9 to wire it as a [VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array#Signal)

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone, I marked this as answer because I think is the most complete, well presented and amazon link is very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Fire-Dragon-DoL, I've had to deal with these a lot in a university computer lab. The uncommon interface does make it a bit of a pain to work with (people often assume it is DVI by its appearance). Having to buy a $25ish dongle isn't fun either :-)

Comment: Yea same here... I thought it was a DVI before discovering the problem. Then I discovered I have to spend around 25€ to buy the splitter >.<

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [DMS-59](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DMS-59), which appears to provide two VGA and two DVI connectors. So using an electrical converter, your task should be achievable.

Answer (score 2):

That's a DMS-59 connector. It's used on work station cards to support two monitors in one output.

Yes you can connect VGA, You will need a convertor to either twin DVI or twin VGA

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a DMS-59 adapter cable, like [this one](http://www.benfranklin.com/item.php?id=DH-DMSDVIDVI1&c=e&s1=Cables%20Audio%20&%20Video&s2=DVI%20&%20DVI%20Combo&gclid=CJXY-omX_LICFdEWMgodNnkACw) that splits to two DVI-D connectors. Then you can hook up two monitors via any combination of DVI or VGA (though with the DMS-59 to DVI-D cable, each VGA will require a DVI-D to VGA adapter).